# Kendo Grouping Not Working

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid and i have grouping enabled in it. The problem is that sometimes the grouping does not work.

It shows a circle with disabled notation in the top.

Below is my grid code:

```
$("#divGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: function (options) {
                    var webMethod = "Portal.aspx/DisplayNotes";
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: webMethod,
                        data: displayParams,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (result) {
                            options.success(result.d);
                        }
                    })
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "ID",
                    fields: {
                        ID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                        IsDeleted: { type: "boolean" },
                        Text: { type: "string" },
                        CreatedByDisplayName: { type: "string" },
                        CreatedDateTime: { type: "date" },
                        Order: { type: "number" },
                        PermissionType: { type: "string" },
                        LastEditedByUserGUID: { type: "string" },
                        GUID: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } },
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 5
        },
        dataBound: onDataBound,
        batch: true,
        edit: function (e) {
            // To stop the Auto Refresh of the grid on edit
            isEditing = true;
        },
        groupable: true,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        reorderable: true,
        toolbar: "<div><img id='imgExportDoc' style='margin-left:15px' onclick='ExportData(1);' title='Export in Word Format' src='images/doc-Icon.png'/><img id='imgExportExcel' onclick='ExportData(2);' style='margin-left:15px' title='Export in Excel Format' src='images/xls-Icon.png'/><img id='imgExportPDF' style='margin-left:15px' onclick='ExportData(3);' title='Export in PDF Format' src='images/pdf_icon.jpg'/></div>",
        resizable: true,
        selectable: "row",
        autoSync: true,
        editable: true,// "inline",
        navigatable: true,
        columnMenu: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
        columns: [
        {
            field: "ID", width: width0, title: "Note ID", template: function (dataItem) {
                if (typeof dataItem.Id != "string") {
                    return "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.google.com\">" + dataItem.ID + "</a>";
                } else {
                    return dataItem.ID;
                }
            }
        },
        { field: "IsDeleted", width: width1, title: "IsDeleted" },
        { field: "Text", title: "Note Text", width: width2 },
        { field: "CreatedDateTime", title: "Created Datetime", width: width3 },
        { field: "Order", title: "Order", width: "140px", width: width4 },
        { field: "PermissionType", title: "Permission Type", width: width5 },
        { field: "LastEditedByUserGUID", title: "Last Edited By", editor: ddlSimpleEditor, width: width6 },
        { command: { text: "Delete", click: deleteNoteData }, title: "Delete", width: width7, menu: false },
        { field: "GUID", hidden: true, title: "Hidden", menu: false, width: width8 }]
        , filterable: true,
        columnMenu: {
            sortable: false
        }
    });
```

What could be a possible reason.

Also want to know how to set the height of a kendo grid dynamically.

Comment: What does _sometimes_ mean? Can you reproduce it, what are the steps?

Comment: Yes actually what happens when I reload the grid with new set of results then in that case i find this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem actually you are not destroying the grid properly before rebinding it:

Below is the code piece for proper destroying:

```
var grid = $("#YourGridName").data("kendoGrid");
        if (grid) {

            //destroy the previous Grid instance
            grid.destroy();

            //clean up the html
            grid.wrapper.html("");
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ user3248355 as far as possible try to do not `destroy` and recreate a  grid, this is an expensive operation in terms of time and memory. You can read new data without destroying it. It uses to be better hide the grid and then show it back after reading the new data.

Comment: @OnaBai The above stated answer solve my problem of grouping on rebinding the grid. Yes there can be a performance hit but my problem is resolved by this.

Comment: @OnaBai Yes destroying and recreating is performance wise an expensive operation but user3248355 was clearing the html of the div for destroying the grid and I just provided a proper way of destroying a grid which also help to solve the grouping problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hi below is the code for the dynamic height:

```
//Below code is for defining the height of the grid
    $(".k-grid-content").height('400');
```

And just refer to the latest Kendo UI assemblies and your grouping problem will be removed.

Comment: Thanks Nitin. Height solution works perfectly for me but even after referring the latest assemblies i am not able to find solution for grouping problem. Actually first time it works properly but when i load the grid again with new result set then grouping does not work.

Comment: Are you clearing the grid before rebinding the data , if yes then how??

Comment: I have a div that i am converting to kendo grid so i am just clearing the Html of that div as $("#divGrid").html('');